# \batchinput (docstrip) in a different directory

Tags: dtx, docstrip

`docstrip`provides the macro `\batchinput`, which calls a separate `ins` file. This file can be in a different directory with, say:

```
\batchinput{../contrib/xx.ins}
```

and they are generated, but in the same directory as the master `ins`. However, I want them to be generated in the same directory as the `dtx/ins` files. I've tried

```
\def\WriteToDir{../contrib/}
```

But then I get

```
! I can't write on file `../contrib/xx.ldf'.
```

**Edit** ... because TeXLive doesn't allow paths beginning with two dots.

I know `\BaseDirectory`, but this is intended for specifing the root directory of the TEX hierarchy (locally, by administrators).

How can I tell `docstrip` the files must be generated in the same directory as the `dtx/ins` files? **Edit** In other words, I wonder if these `ins` files can be run without having to set the path of the corresponding files (only the `ins` one).

Comment: TeX Live and MiKTeX disallow writing in directories above the current one or those specified with a full path.

Comment: Assuming bash, you can say `openout_any=a tex file.ins`; use at your own risk.

Comment: @egreg. Well, assuming bash, I think I can write an script running directly all those `ins` files, intead of using a master `ins`.

Comment: Of course. But this is a security issue, so without specific and explicit user intervention, writing is disallowed except in the current directory or subdirectories thereof.

Comment: Clearly, there is no hope... except moving the `ins` file to the "local" root directory, so that all `ins` files are in subdirectories (`base` and `contrib`). Not very elegant, imo, but it works.

Answer (score 4):

TeX Live sets up his options in the file `texmf.cnf` located in `texlive/20XX/texmf/web2c/` However this file needn't to be edit. You should edit instead the file `texmf.cnf` in the directory `texlive/20XX/`.

In the main file you will find the following hint:

```
% Allow TeX \openin, \openout, or \input on filenames starting with `.'
% (e.g., .rhosts) or outside the current tree (e.g., /etc/passwd)?
% a (any)        : any file can be opened.
% r (restricted) : disallow opening "dotfiles".
% p (paranoid)   : as `r' and disallow going to parent directories, and
%                  restrict absolute paths to be under $TEXMFOUTPUT.
openout_any = p
openin_any = a
```

Based on this information you can edit the file `texmf.cnf` and set up `openout_any=a`

Comment: Thanks, but the `ins` files should work out of the box.

Comment: This was very helpful, thank you!